# sdkman - cannot install java on Ubuntu - permission denied

Tags: software-installation, java

I just installed sdkman on `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS` following the instructions [here](https://sdkman.io/install).
Now, i am trying to install java, but i am getting a permission issue:

## Issue

> user@u:~$ sdk i java
>
> Downloading: java 11.0.11.hs-adpt
>
> In progress...
>
> #################################################################################################################################################################################################### 100.0%Warning: Failed to create the file                                                                                                                                                                         Warning: /home/user/.sdkman/tmp/java-11.0.11.hs-adpt.bin: Permission
> denied
> 0.0%curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
>
> Download has failed, aborting!
>
> Can not install java 11.0.11.hs-adpt at this time...

> ls -lrta .sdkman
> drwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4096 May 31 10:47 tmp

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: One question, why don't you use `apt` for installing the jdk? `apt list openjdk*`

Comment: This is what i ended up doing, but would be nice to be able to use sdkman ;-)

Comment: In eclipse you can still change to different JRE's for executing your code. In my opinion there is no need to install different JDK's, just install the latest version.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same problem when I installed curl using snap.

On stackoverflow I found help :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67541374/nvm-getting-permission-denied-with-nvm-install-command

```
sudo snap remove curl
sudo apt-get install curl
```

After this and restarted bash session sdkman work fine

```
Installing: java 11.0.11-open
Done installing!
```

Comment: Awesome, you are the best Boguslaw! Thanks!

Comment: This helped me as well, I was perplexed as to what went wrong with the installation of `SDKMAN` since I merely did what I always do, didn't even think that `curl` was the culprit. Also, this question was hard to find, so double thanks!

Comment: as always they have to break compatibility, not caring if other things work, and every single person seeing this is going now use apt instead of their favourite snap